# Unable to access an azure web app hosted inside an Application Service Environment ILB using IP address but able to access the same using FQDN

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have hosted an azure web app inside an Application Service Environment -ILB and when i try to access it using the IP address instead of FQDN i get "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable" but the same works when i access using FQDN.
Ex., if a try to access using https://xyz.microsoftdev.microsoft.com it works but if i try to access using https://10.180.47.6 i get the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure web apps hosted on **Public stamps** or **App Service environment** cannot be accessed via IP Address. This is by design.

They can only be accessed via hostnames.

App Service provides you with Virtual IP of a Front End server, which is a shared resource for all the VM's behind this.

[image: App Service architecture]

Here the Front-end uses the HTTP Host header informatio to route the request to the corresponding w3wp.exe process on the worker VM. This logic wont work when using IP Address. It will reach the front-end and will return a HTTP status 404.

Comment: Thank you Kaushal. Do you have any supporting documents

Comment: There are no official docs which mentions this. I am adding explanation so that it can be used .